# Text to Integers in Applab

Tags: parseint, code.org, app-lab

In Code.org's Applab I'm trying to convert the text from a textinput box or a dropdown into an integer so that i can do mathematical functions with it. However, parseInt doesn't seem to work. How do I convert the text into an integer?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others know what you have already tried

Comment: Hi there! Can you elaborate on what's going wrong when you try to use `parseInt`? Simple cases like `parseInt("45") + 45 // 90` seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number()`. For example, `console.log(Number('2') + 2)` outputs `4`.